# how to pass a javascript file to the browser and make it use it?

Tags: javascript, browser, src

this is probably a very basic question, but my googling resulted in irrelevant results.

I want to be able to provide a 2 lines widget for clients, for example, for every video at Youtube you can get the "embed" line for it, you copy paste it to your web page and as a result you have the video on your page, example:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_6mkqolyvVE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen</iframe>
```

another example is the google's + "+1" button :

```
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>
```

My general question is what is going on behind the scenes when a client has these lines in his page?

My specific question is, if I want to provide a 2 lined widget (a

```
<script>
```

line and a

```
<div>
```

line) how do I pass my javascript file to the web client in a way that the browser will know to treat it as a file it should evaluate and execute?

Thanks, and sorry for the messy question.
Jimmy.

Comment: The `<script>` tag tells the browser to execute the file as a script.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a `<script>` tag, then the browser will handle the content as a script. You can define the content inside the start and the end of the script, like this:

```
<script>
    //your code
</script>
```

Or you can specify the location where the script file can be found with the `src` attribute, like this:

```
<script src="http://yourdomain/yourfile.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you by any chance explain what is going on in the server side?
when I am using Apache - and I am just placing my file in its default folder (say, public_html), I have access to the javascript file as you mentioned.
But, I tried using node.js to handle the requests and there it is not happening by itself, does Apache implement URL parsing for me and searches the file in the file system according to the URL?

Comment: On the server-side the tag with its content/src is included into the html. The html is sent to the client-side, where the browser parses the html. When the browser finds a script, then its src is requested/inner text is executed. So, if you have a script with src attribute, then it is included into the html, sent to the client computer where the browser parses the html and then the file is requested. If the src is on the server, then the server side sends the file. If the src is foreign src, then your server-side will not do anything, as you request another server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to create web **widgets** that dynamically create DOM elements. embedded youtube and google +1 are widgets. an Iframe is just one approach to create a widget.

For moreore information on widgets- http://www.techfounder.net/2010/02/05/creating-embedabble-widgets/

Comment: thanks for the good link!
Can you by any chance explain what is going on in the server side? when I am using Apache - and I am just placing my file in its default folder (say, public_html), I have access to the javascript file as you mentioned. But, I tried using node.js to handle the requests and there it is not happening by itself, does Apache implement URL parsing for me and searches the file in the file system according to the URL?
should I ask another question with this specific subject? :)

Comment: Yes- you can have Apache serve your static files, but you should consult on this in another question specific to the subject.